# Shortcut to speak Safari Reading list

Tags: safari, shortcuts-app

The attached Shortcut open Safari Reading list but doesn’t do anything else. How can I edit the shortcut so that it opens Safari Reading list and speaks the text of articles?

[image]

Comment: How did you get the shortcut to open the Reading List?